# Как из новой ветки убрать изменения, попавшие в неё из старой?

Tags: git

Занимался решением задачи в одной ветке, а затем необходимо было создать ещё одну ветку и начать выполнять в ней другую задачу. В момент создания ветки я, видимо, забыл переключиться на master-ветку, поэтому новая ветка создалась не из мастера, а из моей текущей ветки с моими изменениями. Я этого не заметил и сделал уже несколько изменений, вызвал команды:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Some commit"
git push --set-upstream origin BRANCH-NAME
```

Как мне теперь сделать так, чтобы ветка начиналась не с соседней ветки, а с мастера? Т.е. чтобы в ней не было лишних изменений из соседних веток?

Comment: Самый простой вариант -- создать новую ветку от master и сделать cherry pick нескольких нужных коммитов из прошлой ветки. После успешного cherry pick откатить старую ветку до нужного коммита

Comment: @MikhailIonkin название ветки должно остаться прежним. Я пока думаю над тем, чтобы предварительно сохранить нужные мне изменения и делать `git reset --soft HEAD~1` до тех пор, пока ветка не станет идентичной мастеру, а потом просто заново вкомитить только нужные изменения. Так можно?

Comment: Можно и так. Только сначала сделай ответвление текущей ветки, потом вернись в текущую, потом можно откатить до master, и потом из ответвления залить нужные коммиты